# How to group per time interval in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data set below

| Date | Status | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Failed | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 1500 |
| 05/12/2021 23:59 | Successful | 500 |

I want to be able to split the Date time column to have my time

then group the time per an hour interval

Then Summarise to get the below column

I want to get how many count of transactions processed within an hour

then the value within an hour

then have a column that state how many were successful, then another column that state how many failed within an hour

see the output of the desired summarised table below

| Interval | Value | Count | Successful | Failed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 am - 00:59 am | 32,000 | 54 | 40 | 15 |
| 00:59 am - 01:00 am | 42,000 | 55 | 41 | 14 |
| 01:00 am - 02:59 am | 21,400 | 56 | 42 | 14 |
| 03:00 am - 03:59 am | 4,00 | 57 | 43 | 14 |
| 04:00 am - 04:59 am | 543,000 | 58 | 2 | 56 |
| 05:00 am - 05:59 am | 411,000 | 59 | 6 | 53 |

Comment: You probably don't need to provide quite so many lines of data.  For example, if the data is stored in `df`, then you could use `df %>% head(10) %>% dput` to get code that you could paste into your question.  That would be easier than requiring the answerer to manually prepare code.

Comment: Thanks for this
Rectified by editing and reducing the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(glue)

df <- tribble(~Date,    ~Status,    ~Value,
              "05/12/2021 23:59",   "Failed",   500,
              "05/12/2021 23:59",   "Successful",   1500,
              "05/12/2021 23:59",   "Successful",   500,
              "05/12/2021 23:59",   "Successful",   1500,
              "05/12/2021 23:59",   "Successful",   1500,
              "05/12/2021 23:59",   "Failed",   1500)

df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(Datetime = dmy_hms(Date), # convert to datetime format
           Date = as.Date(Datetime), # extract date, if you need it later
           Hour = hour(Datetime))    # extract hour

hourly_value <- df2 %>% 
    group_by(Hour) %>% 
    summarize(Value = sum(Value),
              .groups = "drop")

hourly_count <- df2 %>% 
    count(Hour, Status) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = "Status", values_from = "n")

interval_helper <- tibble(Hour = 0:23,
                          display_hour = str_pad(Hour %% 12, 2, pad = '0'),
                          ampm = if_else(Hour < 12, "am", "pm"),
                          Interval = glue("{display_hour}:00 {ampm} - {display_hour}:59 {ampm}"))

full_join(hourly_value, hourly_count, by = "Hour") %>% 
    replace_na(list(Successful = 0L, Failed = 0L, Value = 0)) %>% 
    left_join(interval_helper, by = "Hour") %>% 
    mutate(Count = Successful + Failed) %>% 
    select(Interval, Value, Count, Successful, Failed)
```

I wasn't exactly sure how your original `Date` column is formatted.  Here I assume it's a string.  Because the exact format of the `Interval` column is important to you, it seemed easier to make and join a separate tibble with the strings you want displayed.

It's important to replace the missing `NA` values with zeros, otherwise the  `Count = Successful + Failed` will secretly fail when only one of them is present.

Comment: Thanks, Micheal 
Is there a way I can have the time is am/pm 
I know that there is a Fstring using glue but I've tried a couple of options to have the time in am /pm , is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.